# Access a Jquery function after a click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am having this html code:

```html
<form class="add-to-cart-form">
         <input type="hidden" name="product-code" value="2" />
         <input type="submit" value="Add" class="button" onclick="addToCart('2');"/>
    </form>
```

And a javascript code:

```js
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
        quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                alert(json.message);
            }
        });
    }
```

IN the html file anytime, I click on the submit button, instead of taking me to the function `addToCart`, the form is submitted.

I am new to javascript and really don't know the source of the problem. Kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: change type `submit` to `button`

Comment: hardly see reason for having form since you don't reference any of the inputs in it. But basic issue is doing ajax doesn't tell browser not to submit the form through default browser process

Comment: add `return false` to onclick attribute

Comment: @charlietfl the reason is progressive enhancement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking a submit button has a default action of submitting the form.  If that's not what you want to do, you have to prevent it.

```
<form class="add-to-cart-form">
     <input type="hidden" name="product-code" value="2" />
     <input type="submit" value="Add" class="button" onclick="event.preventDefault();addToCart('2');"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of preventing the default action, we can just change the type of the input element to button (as suggested in one of the comments).